# What makes a continuous function on open interval integrable?

Tags: integration, continuity, lebesgue-integral

Let $a < b$. Let $f: (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. What is a sufficient condition to make $f$ integrable (in the Lebesgue sense) on $(0, 1)$?

For example, $f: (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1/x$ is continuous on $(0, 1$). However, it is not integrable as $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0+} \int_{x}^1 dt/t = +\infty$.

In contrast, $f: (0, 1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=x^2$ is both continuous and integrable on $(0, 1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a close analogue of continuous functions on closed intervals being integrables, any function that is continuous and bounded on an open interval is integrable.